# Изменяющийся hashcode

Tags: java, hashcode

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня имеется класс все поля которого изменяемые из вне. Понадобилось переопределить для этого класса метод `equals()`. Согласно правилу необходимо изменить и метод `hashCode()`. Но вот проблема: все поля объекта используемые в методе `equals()` для сравнения часто меняют свои значения и если я буду использовать их для расчета `hashCode`, то для одного и того же объекта его `hashcode` будет меняться со временем.

Первый вопрос: как в этом случае следует переопределить `hashCode()`?

И второй: соблюдать правило: "для одного и того же объекта методе `hashCode()` должен возвращать одно и тоже значение" нужно только если мы собираемся использовать объекты класса в качестве ключей с коллекциями основанными на хешировании? Иначе это не обязательно?

Answer (score 2):

В описанной Вами ситуации не вижу никакой проблемы. Изменение состояния объекта влечет за собой изменение значения хэшкода, и это нормально, так и должно быть.

По поводу второго вопроса: при переопределении `equals()` всегда переопределяйте `hashCode()`, оно, может быть, понадобится не всегда, но если вдруг понадобится, то Вы будете долго искать причину возникшей проблемы, если не переопределите `hashCode()`.